# Wrong item deleted in v-for component [choosing the right :key in v-for]

Tags: caching, vue.js, vue-component, v-for, virtual-dom

I have two components like follows:

```js
     Vue.component('comp-child', {
         template: `<div>{{childData.name}}<slot></slot>{{randomNum}}</div>`,
         props: {
             parentData: {
             }
         },
         data() {
             return {
                 childData: {},
                 randomNum: Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
             };
         },
         created() {
             this.childData.name = this.parentData.name;
         }
     });
     Vue.component('comp-parent', {
         template: `<div><component v-for="(item, index) in arr" is="comp-child" :key="index" :parent-data="item">
             <button @click="deleteItem(index)">delete</button>
         </component>
         </div>`,
         data(){
             return {
                 arr: [{
                     name:1
                 }, {
                     name:2
                 }, {
                     name:3
                 }, {
                     name:4
                 }, {
                     name:5
                 }]
             };
         },
         methods: {
             deleteItem(index) {
                 this.arr.splice(index, 1);
                 console.log(`${index}th element deleted! `);
               
             }
         }
     });
     let app = new Vue({
         el: '#app'
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
    <comp-parent></comp-parent>
</div>
```

In this demo, no matter which item you click, the last item always be deleted.

I located this problem caused by `key` of `v-for`, if use `1, 2, 3, 4,..` as key, this problem occurs, but use others value as key like string, it just works fine;

```
template: `<div><component v-for="(item, index) in arr" is="comp-child" :key="item.key" :parent-data="item">
             <button @click="deleteItem(index)">delete</button>
         </component>
         </div>`,
         data(){
             return {
                 arr: [{
                     name:1,
                     key: 'key1'
                 }, {
                     name:2,
                     key: 'key2'
                 }, {
                     name:3,
                     key: 'key3'
                 }, {
                     name:4,
                     key: 'key4'
                 }, {
                     name:5,
                     key: 'key5'
                 }]
             };
         },
```

check this fiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/IanZhong/hv904d2a/9/)

Does it caused by virtual DOM? It seems VUE bind key and children components as cache, when `arr` changed, it just re-render components in index(1,2,3,..)'s order, if some item in `arr` is deleted, the length of `arr` decreasing cause the last one cannot be render.

Please someone explain this to me, Thanks!

Comment: You should pass key to remove an item from the array. Because Vue documentation recommends to not use an index as a key

Comment: @latovic, if key is 1,2,3……, pass key to remove an item still cause this problem, isn't it? so I want to know why using index to remove doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use v-for, **your key has to be some piece of data that is unique to the item in question**. Index is no good because it doesn't identify the item. Just changing the key to item.name gets your example to work perfectly.

In your example, your source array was being modified correctly, but vue was reusing previously generated component instances to display the modified array, and these instances had left-over state. Vue does this for performance reasons and it's not normally a problem, but it does highlight the importance of choosing the right key.

Your problem was made worse by a couple of little things that you don't often see in nature, and that you should probably avoid... assigning parentData.name to childData.name in the created hook: because your children were getting reused, not recreated, the childData.name became stale. The same goes for the random number.

```js
Vue.component('comp-child', {
         template: `<div>{{childData.name}}<slot></slot>{{randomNum}}</div>`,
         props: {
             parentData: {
             }
         },
         data() {
             return {
                 childData: {},
                 randomNum: Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
             };
         },
         created() {
             this.childData.name = this.parentData.name;
         }
     });
     Vue.component('comp-parent', {
         template: `<div><component v-for="(item, index) in arr" is="comp-child" :key="item.name" :parent-data="item">
             <button @click="deleteItem(index)">delete</button>
         </component>
         </div>`,
         data(){
             return {
                 arr: [{
                     name:1
                 }, {
                     name:2
                 }, {
                     name:3
                 }, {
                     name:4
                 }, {
                     name:5
                 }]
             };
         },
         methods: {
             deleteItem(index) {
                 this.arr.splice(index, 1);
                 console.log(`${index}th element deleted! `);
               
             }
         }
     });
     let app = new Vue({
         el: '#app'
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
    <comp-parent></comp-parent>
</div>
```

Comment: Any suggestion of what can be used as key if there is no unique field?

Comment: You can always assign unique keys to your array, if there's nothing in their already. Keys are a fundamental requirement for keeping the DOM in sync with your array in your model.